# Add blank space at end of NSString

Tags: objective-c

I am using NSString class to display a string with a format like ' STRING ' a empty space should display in begining and end of string

My code is

```
NSMutableString *MUT_STR = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@" TEST"];
    [MUT_STR insertString:@" " atIndex: MUT_STR.length];
```

I tried like the following code also

```
NSString *STR_test = @" TEST ";
```

At present my output is like 
' TEST'

Thanks

Comment: why you are not tried with `NSString *finalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ ",STR_test];`
`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I tried that also while displaying in label that space at the end of string is not displayed

Comment: can you update the question based on your try

Comment: How do you display the string?

Answer (score 2):

you can do this in multiple ways.

for e.g

```
// add the space in in front of string
NSString *finalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@",STR_test];
// calculate the string length and append the space in end of the string
NSString *result = [finalString stringByPaddingToLength:MAX(finalString.length + 1, STR_test.length)
                                      withString:@" " startingAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"final Result:\'%@\'", result);
```

another simple option

```
// add space in start and end of the string

NSString *finalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ ",STR_test];
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I tried with what you do, its give perfect output at my end. Check the attached screen shots.

[image]

If you still having issue then you can use below code:

```
    NSString *STR_test = @" TEST";
    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",STR_test];
NSLog(@"%@",result);
```

This is what I tried:

NSString *STR_test = @" TEST";
    //    NSLog(@"%@",STR_test);

```
NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",STR_test];
NSLog(@"%@",result);

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 300, 50)];
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",result];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[label sizeToFit];
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

**OUTPUT:**
[image]

Comment: Yeah but when I try to display in label it is not showing it

Comment: I am trying by overriding UILabel. But the label is displaying attributed text

Comment: Did you get the error? or it's not going to work for you?

Comment: no but in beginning space displayed and end no space is shown

Comment: Try to set sizeToFit to label and change background color of your label and check it.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and it worked for me

NSString *reqString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",@"",@"YourString",@""];
    NSLog(@"%@",reqString);

Pass the string in place of your string.

Comment: In console it is working but my text is dynamic also to display in label what should I do it is a attributed text

Answer (score 0):

**Swift**

```
    let str = "Hello"
    var finalStr: String = " \(str)"
    let result = finalStr.padding(toLength: max((finalStr.characters.count) + 1, (str.characters.count)), withPad: " ", startingAt: 0)
    print("Result:\'\(result)\'")
```

Comment: i agree your concept is based on my logic but whre is the first space

Comment: Can you please reply the same in objective c

Comment: You can check answer of @Anbu.Karthik in objective c

Comment: you can give upvote for swift so that it can help to others.. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Try as below:

```
NSString *MUT_STR = @" TEST";
MUT_STR = [MUT_STR stringByAppendingString:@" "];
NSLog(@"%@",MUT_STR);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code looks good for the expected result.

Case 1

```
NSMutableString *MUT_STR = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@" TEST"];
[MUT_STR insertString:@" " atIndex: MUT_STR.length];
NSLog(@"output : |%@|",MUT_STR);
self.lbl.text = MUT_STR;
```

[With trailing and leading spaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6vtv.png)

Case 2

```
NSMutableString *MUT_STR = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"TEST"];
[MUT_STR insertString:@" " atIndex: MUT_STR.length];
NSLog(@"output : |%@|",MUT_STR);
self.lbl.text = MUT_STR;
```

Case 3

```
NSMutableString *MUT_STR = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@" TEST"];
//[MUT_STR insertString:@" " atIndex: MUT_STR.length];
NSLog(@"output : |%@|",MUT_STR);
self.lbl.text = MUT_STR;
```

Case 4 attributed text

```
NSMutableString *MUT_STR = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@" TEST"];
[MUT_STR insertString:@" " atIndex: MUT_STR.length];
NSLog(@"output : |%@|",MUT_STR);
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor blueColor] forKey:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName];

NSAttributedString *attStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:MUT_STR attributes:attributes];

//self.lbl.text = MUT_STR;
self.lbl.attributedText = attStr;
```

[blue area is where there is text content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aUHt.png)

Make sure you are not trimming out trailing spaces or not replacing blank spaces anywhere within the code flow

Comment: I am not using auto layout in this page also the label should display attributed text

Comment: This works without auto layout also, it was included to identify the edges of the label.
NSMutableString *MUT_STR = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@" TEST"];
    [MUT_STR insertString:@" " atIndex: MUT_STR.length];
    NSLog(@"output : |%@|",MUT_STR);
    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor blueColor] forKey:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName];
    
    NSAttributedString *attStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:MUT_STR attributes:attributes];
    
    //self.lbl.text = MUT_STR;
    self.lbl.attributedText = attStr;

Updated my answer

Comment: Last day I encountered a similar issue with autolayout in swift 3. I added a '\t' at the end like " TEST\t" and displayed the same to the UILabel and the trailing space was not trimmed out. Try it out which may help you

Comment: but \t gives more space 1 space will be fine @Ajith

Comment: in my case, the space (" ") get trimmed out from the end but \t is adding a space at the end (same as what we expect from " "). I am using an auto-layout constraints to expand/collapse the label based on the available text content @AJSanjay

Comment: Oh My self I am not using auto layout